# function which contains read and write from two table in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have two table in mnesia which have this format :

```
mnesia:create_table(person,
   [{disc_copies, [node()]},
    {attributes, record_info(fields, person)}]),
mnesia:create_table(person_backup,
   [{disc_copies, [node()]},
    {attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
    {record_name, person}]),
```

I want to develop a function which has this role :

read all data from the table person 
then write this data in the table person_backup

I try with a function of backup (it's your code)

```
testbackup()->

    mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
  Records = mnesia:select(person, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]),
  [ok = mnesia:write(person_backup, Record, write) || Record <- Records]
end).
```

and when I run this function I have this message

```
 model:testbackup().
{atomic,[ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,
         ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok,ok|...]}
```

it work perfectly  mean in the table person_backup I have the same data of the table person

but when I do model:reset().

the data of the table person and the table person_backup will deleted

and normally juste the data of person will be deleted

the code of reset()  is :

```
reset() ->
    stop(),
    destroy(),
    create(),
    start(),

    {ok}.


destroy() ->
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:delete_table(counter),
    mnesia:delete_table(person),
    mnesia:stop(),
    mnesia:delete_schema([node()]).


create() ->
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:create_table(counter, [{attributes, record_info(fields, counter)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),
    mnesia:create_table(person, [{attributes, record_info(fields, person)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),
  mnesia:create_table(person_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
    {record_name, person}]),
    mnesia:stop().
```

And I try to resolve this probleme in another way

I have a function **testcreate**

```
testcreate()->

    %% mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),

    mnesia:create_table(person_backup, [{attributes, record_info(fields, person_backup)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]).
```

and in the record I have

```
-record(person, {id, token, password, pin, key, salt, pin_salt, subscription_date, first_name, last_name, alias, gender, status,
                 taxid, formid, idcard, birth_year, birth_month, birth_date}).
-record(person_backup, {id, token, password, pin, key, salt, pin_salt, subscription_date, first_name, last_name, alias, gender, status,
                 taxid, formid, idcard, birth_year, birth_month, birth_date}).
```

when I run the function **testbackup** I have this message

```
 2> model:testbackup().
    {aborted,{bad_type,{person,215,"97808233",
                               "bddcba13effb029e93aaab6fdc3c4587",
                               "d707aa5f940a468e149686b3eaafd946",
                               "230d8294d47f6fa2cc1761deab52a879",
                               "1360713353326653","1360713353326653",undefined,
                               "souad","sallami",[],"M.","preregistered",
                               undefined,"Z008022","04705808","CIN",[],
                               "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e","0","user",0,
                               {{...},...},
                               undefined,...}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
  Records = mnesia:select(person, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]),
  [ok = mnesia:write(person_backup, Record, write) || Record <- Records]
end).
```